# To separate substring from string

Tags: java, string, substring

I have this string in java variable as

```java
String t = "C:/clearpath/rafa.jpg";
```

Now I want to remove `clearpath` from variable `t` and want to store in other variable as

```java
String j = "C://rafa.jpg".
```

How am i supposed to do this?

Comment: clearpath is a constant name ?

Comment: No, It's not constant

Comment: In this case  you should explain more specifically the rule of the path to strip

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) maybe? `String path = "clearpath"; String j = t.replace(path, "");`

Comment: @StefanBecker  thnks , I'll try.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with

```
t=t.replace("clearpath","");
```

Comment: `String.remove()` doesn't exist.

Comment: I'll try this, thnks.

Comment: It is possible using a regex too:
`t=t.replaceAll(regex,"");`
e.g.
`t=t.replaceAll("/.*/","//");`

Answer (score 0):

This works for that string.

```
String t = "C:/clearpath/rafa.jpg";
t = t.substring(0, 3) + t.substring(12, t.length());
```

Comment: I posted another question,please help me with that

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `java.nio.file.Path`.
By using `Path` you can manipulate your path in many ways.

In your case, you can get the file name by

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/clearpath/rafa.jpg");
Path fileNm = path.getFileName();
```

& file root as

```
Path fileRoot = path.getRoot();
```

At the end, simply concatenate them together.

```
System.out.println(fileRoot.toString() + fileNm.toString());
```

The final output will be like

```
C:\rafa.jpg
```

Comment: Add `File.separatorChar` while concatenate as `fileRoot.toString() + File.separatorChar + fileNm.toString()` so you will get output as `C:\\rafa.jpg`